# Retrieve Outlook calendar info in JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, outlook, calendar, office365

I'm trying to write a web page for a musician friend. I want to get gig info from her Outlook calendar so I can put it on the page. I've been going in circles all day trying to find the right way to do this. Some info is out of date. Some tell me to do things that don't exist. Etc.

All I need to do is read info, probably from a specific "gigs" calendar, or even from her default. I will never have to write info or access anything else. I've created my own outlook calendar to play with, but am stuck cold.

It's seems to me that there should be some simple AJAX call that could do this (so I can manipulate it with JS), but I can't find one that works. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

If that can't be done, I'd at least like to be able to embed an Outlook calendar on the page. I did something similar years ago with a google calendar and that was easy. Now, I keep getting told I have to go get a link, but I follow the directions and there is no link.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can export to CSV from Outlook and use something like [this  CSVToArray();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data) method.

Comment: As I understand what you're suggesting, that doesn't fit my needs. I'm sure I can log into the calendar and download the calendar in some format. But I'm talking about the web page doing this automatically, every time someone goes to the page - JS makes an AJAX call to the web page and gets a file (JSON, XML, CSV, whatever) in return that the JS can parse and put the info dynamically into the HTML. If I've misunderstood your answer, please clarify. If you think my approach won't work, please let me know.